# How to dynamically sort a list in c# by datagrid Source

Tags: c#, sorting, dynamic

Here it is, I have a `DatagridView` bound to a list of objects - that's fine.
What I do is list 10 or so results at a time, where the results can be navigated with next and previous buttons that simply get the results out of the source and display them.

The issue is that I want the source to order by what ever column is clicked in the Datagrid view - not just the results being viewed at the time, all of the results.

I have finally started to get close. I can compare my source and even set an order by the name of the column being used to invoke the data value.
What I need to know is can I have it set the data type automatically:

```
AppSettings.Instance.SearchResults.Sort(
    new Comparison<SearchResult>(
        (x, y) =>
        ((Int32) x.GetType().GetProperty("Links").GetValue(x, null)).CompareTo(
            ((Int32) y.GetType().GetProperty("Links").GetValue(y, null)))));
```

Here I have set the property to Links, which is an Int. I cannot make use of `CompareTo` without converting the value even though it knows its an `Int32`. Some values I compare will be of the type `DateTime` so I need to know if its possible to compare and get the data type dynamically as I'm so close now.

Summary - I would like to automatically identify the data type of dynamically invoked property values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's the best 'way forward', to do you what you wanna do.

**if applicable I'd rather use `IComparable<T>`** instead e.g.

```
int BetterComparison<T>(T x, T y) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

And call it like:

```
BetterComparison(10, 20);
BetterComparison(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```

**If you'd still want to resort to reflection for some reason** (or have things more generic in nature - or not defined by any interface like that)...

You should `reflect` on the `CompareTo` method for the specific type - and then just invoke with values you have. E.g. something like this (within your method):

```
// x.GetType() and y.GetType() should be interchangable by the nature of it
var compareMethod = x.GetType().GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { y.GetType() });
return (int)compareMethod.Invoke(x, new object[]{y});
```

That allows you to call it like this:

```
var ret1 = Comparison(10, 20);
var ret2 = Comparison(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```